# How to inject HttpClientTestingModule in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test an service that use HttpCliente, I have this:

```
export class LoginService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config: AppConfig,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {}
```

so, in the .spec:

```
describe('LoginService', () => {
  let service;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [LoginService, AuthService, AppConfig]
    });
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(LoginService);
  });
```

but, it's not working because i couldn't import Inject, this error appears: Property 'inject' does not exist on type 'TestBedStatic', how can I import the inject?
and, other question, it's fine the configure of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestBed.inject` was introduced in Angular 9, in Angular 7 you should use `TestBed.get`. You can check it in [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#get)

Regarding test configuration:
It looks fine. In general, it's a good practice to add:

```
afterEach(() => {
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

when using `HttpTestingController`